# I need to disable/switch print screen key in DOS with TurboPascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, dos, turbo-pascal

Can anyone help me with that? Sorry for not being specific, but that is what I must do. I have no idea about how can i do that, is there a way to reassign keys directly from TurboPascal?

Comment: I think you can replace the [int $05 handler](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0033.htm) with an empty one. What I want to know, though, is how you managed to build a time machine to get here from 1988 and why you don't just get the lotto numbers and travel back to last week ;)

Comment: And how do you propose to stop someone running your program in a virtual machine and defeating what you did?

Comment: well, I assume you have SWAG and spelled out the "keyboard" section ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to replace the [int $05 handler](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0033.htm) with an empty one as suggested by [*@500 - Internal Server Error*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32874677/i-need-to-disable-switch-print-screen-key-in-dos-with-turbopascal#comment53583194_32874677).